# Columns as many as 24 and rows as many as 100 in the listView

Tags: android, database, performance, listview, scroll

The idea is that I want to make a view which can have many columns so it needs the horizontal scroll and as I am using ListView so the the intention is also for the vertical scroll. I do not want to use ViewFlipper kind of stuff.

And another reason I am using ListView and not TableLayout is because I am concerned about the performance. With listview we have adapter and recycler which makes the performance really good.

Anybody Any clue please??

Edit: I have changed the caption of my problem for better understanding of the issue.

Comment: I don't think you will experience to much of a performance degradation with the usage of a TableLayout. Especially with the fancy new hardware that's being released. Just stick with the TableLayout.

Comment: Hmm, I was just wondering the possibility of having a ListView of Gallery items. I haven't tried that, but you could give it a try.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA : the maximum number of columns I have will not be more than 24 but the rows can go as much as 100 or 1000, so what do you suggest?

Comment: Thanks guys for the help but I have edited my question for better understanding. so what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that I cannot make the kind of design I am trying to do with the ListView, so I should rather stick to the Tablelayout design only and use the Async task for performance. But I have to work on this. Once it works, I will put my design here.